# Android AppCompat-v21 Toolbar Animation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, material-design

I want to use new Android Toolbar pattern instead of ActionBar.
I add a Toolbar as SupportActionBar from appCompat v21 and now, I want to hide/show it with animation while scrolling listView items.
before, I use methods: actionBar.show() and actionBar.hide() and it animate automatically. but now, in Toolbar it hide and show without any animation.
What should I do???

Activity Layout:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actionbar_margin" />
```

Toolbar Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:id="@+id/toolbarActionbar_T_actionToolbar"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Activity Java:

```
actionToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarActionbar_T_actionToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(actionToolbar);
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: code & screenshots please

Comment: A `ToolBar` is just a `ViewGroup`, so any [view animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) (or [property animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views) if you're targetting API level 11+) will work.

Comment: @MH. is right. Use any kind of animation. And there is a great library for that (and other good animations) https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you need is a scroll listener. It detects whether you scroll up or down and hides or shows the Toolbar accordingly. Also known as the '[Quick Return](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks/src/com/example/android/scrolltricks/QuickReturnFragment.java)' pattern.

Apart from just using the hide() and show() methods, for the animation, you must do it like this:

For hiding:

```
toolbarContainer.animate().translationY(-toolbarHeight).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
```

For showing the Toolbar:

```
 toolbarContainer.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
```

For further reading, you can refer this [tutorial](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/implement-floating-action-button-fab-part-2/).It talks about a Floating Action Button, but its the same animation for a Toolbar. Or find its code at [GitHub](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop/blob/master/MaterialSample/app/src/main/java/com/suleiman/material/activities/FabHideActivity.java).

You can do this quite simply without any external library. :-)

### UPDATE

You no longer need to manually maintain any listener. The Design Support library by Android enables you to do this with pure XML.

Here's the XML Snippet to enable a Quick Return:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

The key lies in this line:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

You can read more about implementing Quick Return with the Design Support library, [here](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/quick-return-pattern-with-android-design-support-library/).

Answer (score 12):

Add the below line in the xml that is parent to the toolbar.

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Comment: A quick fix solution. The animation is different from what hide() do.

Comment: Does the job but doesn't animate by sliding from top. Animation is fade in and fade out.

Comment: 2019. Same problem. I tried to manually start the animation, but with no success. This flag on the parent view solved like a charm and my code still clean without animation hacks. :)